# built library dirs not added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in libtool wrapper script

Tags: c, automake, libtool

I cannot easily test my program after build:

```
$ ./src/rap/rap -h
/home/il/workspace/rap/src/rap/.libs/lt-rap: error while loading shared libraries: libpmclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`libpmclient.so` is in `./src/nsreclient/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/` and a proper `-L` flag was used during link

Automake builds my binary with libtool. It creates a wrapper script `src/rap/rap`.

My expectation was: while generating the script, libtool would ignore the current value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. When running the script, it would *append* the needed directories in the build tree to existing value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. e.g, executing:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo ./src/rap/rap
```

would result:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/foo:/home/il/workspace/rap/src/nsreclient/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu ./src/rap/.libs/lt-rap
```

But libtool does the opposite: it hardcodes the current value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` into the generated script:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_64/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
```

It makes no sense. Why doesn't it add there the build tree directories?

Here's pretty formated output of make command:

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -O2 \
    -pthread   -o rap rap.o \
    librap.a \
    ../liclib/liblic.a \
    ../fget-1.3.3/lib/libfget.a \
    ../lib_mt/libppb.la \
    ../sgplib/libsgp.la \
    ../../variations/asn1lib/ebuf_lib_mt/libasn1cebuf.la \
    -L../../src/nsreclient/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpmclient \
    -L/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_64/lib -lclntsh \
    -L/usr/lib -lexpat \
    -lssl \
    -lcrypto  \
    -lm


libtool: link: gcc -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -O2 -pthread -o .libs/rap rap.o  librap.a ../liclib/liblic.a ../fget-1.3.3/lib/libfget.a \
    ../lib_mt/.libs/libppb.so \
    ../sgplib/.libs/libsgp.so \
    ../../variations/asn1lib/ebuf_lib_mt/.libs/libasn1cebuf.so \
    -L../../src/nsreclient/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpmclient \
    -L/opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_64/lib -lclntsh \
    -L/usr/lib /usr/lib/libexpat.so \
    -lssl -lcrypto -lm -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: You've said that the library is in `/src/nsreclient/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/`, however that script doesn't add that directory to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.  Isn't that the issue?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes. (`./src/...` )

Comment: So you need to edit the script that sets `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  Or are you after something else?

Comment: I wonder why doesn't libtool do that already

Comment: how are you linking?  can you show the `Makefile.am` portions?

Comment: @umläute http://pastebin.com/j8ryptV3

Comment: is building `libpmclient` part of your build-process? is it build with libtool? is there a `libpmclient.la`? if so, why don't you use that? your pastie only has `$(PMCLIENT_LDFLAGS) $(PMCLIENT_LIBS)` where it should get interesting...

Comment: @umläute No, it's 3rd-party precompiled .so for current build target. In ./configure I detect target triplet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper script does not set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at all. It assumes that subdirs containing the needed libraries were added to `RPATH` of the real binary.

When `-lfoo` flag passed to `libtool`, it first tries to open the corresponding file `libfoo.la`. If that file does not exist, `libtool` falls back to passing the flag to `gcc` unchanged.

If the `.la` file exists and points to a shared library, `libtool` tells the linker to add the directory containing the library to `RPATH` of output binary.

Many packages install their `.la` files to `/usr/lib/`. That means newer `libtool` will be able parse files created by previous versions. It must be totally safe to manually write `.la` files for precompiled `.so` files instead of generating them every time.

I created the file `./src/nsreclient/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libpmclient.la` :

```
# libpmclient.la - a libtool library file
# Generated by ltmain.sh - GNU libtool 1.5.22 (1.1220.2.365 2005/12/18 22:14:06)
#
# Please DO NOT delete this file!
# It is necessary for linking the library.

# The name that we can dlopen(3).
dlname='libpmclient.so'

# Names of this library.
library_names='libpmclient.so'

# The name of the static archive.
old_library='libpmclient.a'

# Linker flags that cannot go in dependency_libs.
inherited_linker_flags=' -pthread'

# Libraries that this one depends upon.
dependency_libs=''

# Names of additional weak libraries provided by this library
weak_library_names=''

# Version information for libpmclient.
current=0
age=0
revision=0

# Is this an already installed library?
installed=no

# Should we warn about portability when linking against -modules?
shouldnotlink=no

# Files to dlopen/dlpreopen
dlopen=''
dlpreopen=''

# Directory that this library needs to be installed in:
libdir='/usr/local/lib'
```

After rebuild, my wrapper script no longer complains.

Answer (score 0):

there is a misunderstanding what `libtool` and it's wrapper-script does for you.
esp. it will *not* parse the all the flags passed to the linker for library paths (`-L`) and add them to some `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable for you.

the libtool wrapper script's purpose is to (cf [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Linking-executables.html)) cater for running *uninstalled applications* with

> [any] uninstalled libtool library.

now `libtool libraries` are those weirdo `.la` files (rather than the actual dynamic libraries with the `.so` suffix).

since your `libpmclient.so` is no such beast, the wrapper script won't help you much here.

## solution?

if you cannot *install* your 3rd party libraris to a place where the runtime linker can find them, i would suggest to add the needed paths to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and source that config-file whenever you go hacking (you *could* also do this in your `~/.bashrc`, but then it might get in your ways later, if you use your account for different things than coding on that single project)

Comment: I have 2 other libraries that have a `.la` file: `../lib_mt/libppb.la` and `../sgplib/libsgp.la`. They're not added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but my binary *can* find them.

Comment: Maybe it's better to manually write a `.la` file for the 3rd-party .so?